# Generate All Replacements for List of Lists

Tags: python, list, recursion

I'm building an application in Python where I need to define the following sort of function:

```
generate_replacements(['a', 'b', ['c', ['e', 'f']]], 1)
```

The expected output is all possible versions of the input list where just one element has been replaced

```
[
[1, 'b', ['c', ['e', 'f']]],
['a', 1, ['c', ['e', 'f']]],
['a', 'b', 1],
['a', 'b', [1, ['e', 'f']]],
['a', 'b', ['c', 1]],
['a', 'b', ['c', [1, 'f']]],
['a', 'b', ['c', ['e', 1]]]
]
```

I can see that recursion is the way to go, but I'm really stuck figuring out how to even best start this.

Comment: Did you mean `[a, b, [c, [e, f]]]` with comma after `b`?

Comment: Yes, I've just fixed this and cleaned it up a bit more

Comment: You can definitely use recursion here (and it's not a bad idea), although you never have to. How would you approach the problem doing it by hand? Have you tried writing any code at all, perhaps starting with how you would do it by hand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate the replacements from the list, then if you notice you are replacing a list, also pass that list back through the function recursively. This is made a bit simpler if you use a generator:

```
def generate_replacements(l, rep):
    for i in range(len(l)):
        yield l[0:i] + [rep] + l[i+1: ]
        if isinstance(l[i], list):
            yield from (l[0:i] + [rec] + l[i+1: ] 
                        for rec in generate_replacements(l[i], rep))


list(generate_replacements(['a', 'b', ['c', ['e', 'f']]], 1))
```

This give:

```
[[1, 'b', ['c', ['e', 'f']]],
 ['a', 1, ['c', ['e', 'f']]],
 ['a', 'b', 1],
 ['a', 'b', [1, ['e', 'f']]],
 ['a', 'b', ['c', 1]],
 ['a', 'b', ['c', [1, 'f']]],
 ['a', 'b', ['c', ['e', 1]]]]
```

Comment: This helped me get a better grasp of yield from, thanks! :)